# How to know if a MFC message loop is already running?

Tags: c++, c, mfc, loops, message

Is there any way to know whether a MFC message loop is already running?

**EDIT**: Context: A library (with event handling) needs to know whether its event filtering has to attach to an existing MFC message loop or create its own message loop: in case a main message loop already exists it must not create its own loop because it would be blocking.

Comment: In what situation? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do it without waiting some time, for instance while trying to send an event and wait for it, or wait 5 sec using a special MFC function which is dedicated to detect stalled applications (which one? I can't remember its name...).

If you need to do it, find another way, make other assumptions. Sorry.